# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

I am having an error with Web3. After going through all possibilities I decided to post a question hoping for someone with a solution.

The error I keep getting is:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {
   web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]).then(balance => {
      console.log(balance);
    }
}
```

**Note: this exact same code is running fine on two other servers. I do have the exact same versions of Truffle, React..etc as the other two.**

Any solutions will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the web3 version you use?

Comment: Things related to `.then` have changed with version, you should specify your web3 version in question.

Comment: You need at least web3 v1.0 because it has support for promises, for version v0.20 it only supported callbacks, you have to use a third party library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) to promisify functions.

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add a catch in order to output the stacktrace of your error ?

Just add at the end of your promise chain : `then(account => {...}).catch( err => { console.log(err); }`

You'll then be able to see in the console the stacktrace of the error and distinguish if it is accounts or accounts[0] which is undefined.

If it is `accounts[0]`, ensure your web3 instance is connected.
If is is the whole `accounts` object, ensure you use Web3.js `v1.x.x` and not `v.0.2.x`

Comment: unfortunately somehow my error was thrown before this catch was in effect, possibly because I used jQuery.  ```jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in an asynchronous function:

```
private async deployContract(): Promise<string> {
  web3.eth.getAccounts().then...
  ...
  return Promise.resolve('Check done');
}
```